PLS-00201 error when creating a trigger for a sequence when inserting
I want to create a trigger, so SEQNUM gets a next value everytime an insert is done in the table.
This is the script to create the trigger:
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JITEM_TG
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON MYSCHEMA.JITEM_A
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
      :NEW.SEQNUM := MYSCHEMA.JITEM_SEQ.NEXTVAL ;
    END;

The script gets executed, a trigger is created, but there is a compile error:
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
2/19    PLS-00201: identifier 'MYSCHEMA.JITEM_SEQ' must be declared
2/4     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
 (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Now, in the table all_triggers I can find the trigger.
But the trigger does not work. When an insert is done following error is given:
[Error] Execution (10: 19): ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSADM.JITEM_TG' is invalid and failed re-validation

The sequence is working, so for example when I execute following statment it is given me the next value:
select MYSCHEMA.JITEM_SEQ.nextval from dual;

Searched for similar issues, but did not find any answers that appeared applicable.
Or found the answer, where the answer is exactly as the script I am trying to execute. (mostly a colon or semicolon missing, but I think that's fine in my script)

Did you, by any chance, create that sequence and enclosed its name into double quotes?
Have a look at the following demo:
Sample table:
SQL> CREATE TABLE jitem_a
  2  (
  3     seqnum   NUMBER,
  4     name     VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );

Table created.

Sequence; note lower letter case and double quotes:
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE "jitem_seq";

Sequence created.

Trigger:
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JITEM_TG
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON JITEM_A
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     :NEW.SEQNUM := JITEM_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
  7  END;
  8  /

Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

Errors? What errors?! Your errors!
SQL> show err
Errors for TRIGGER JITEM_TG:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/4      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
2/19     PLS-00201: identifier 'JITEM_SEQ.NEXTVAL' must be declared

If you used mixed letter case and double quotes, you must use the same when referencing such an object:
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JITEM_TG
  2     BEFORE INSERT
  3     ON JITEM_A
  4     FOR EACH ROW
  5  BEGIN
  6     :NEW.SEQNUM := "jitem_seq".NEXTVAL;       --> here
  7  END;
  8  /

Trigger created.

OK, now it is created. Does it work? Yes, it does:
SQL> INSERT INTO jitem_a (name) VALUES ('Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM jitem_a;

    SEQNUM NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Littlefoot

SQL>


If that's really the case, I'd suggest you to remove double quotes entirely when working with Oracle.

No quotes were used when creating the sequence. This is the statement: CREATE SEQUENCE MYSCHEMA.JITEM_SEQ START WITH 1;
